# Using derived table and GROUP BY on 2 columns on MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, derived-table

I'm using a MySQL Server instance with certain constraints (no CTE, not able to create temporary tables or even new tables), so the only way allowed to solve it is using derived tables.

I have the following table `t`, containing each occurrence of each selling on each month (1-12):

```
+------+-----------+-----------------+
|  id  |  product  |  sold_on_month  |
+------+-----------+-----------------+
|   1  | Product 1 |        1        |
|   2  | Product 1 |        2        |
|   3  | Product 1 |        2        |
|   4  | Product 1 |        3        |
|   5  | Product 1 |        3        |
|   6  | Product 1 |        4        |
|   7  | Product 1 |        4        |
|   8  | Product 1 |        4        |
|   9  | Product 1 |        4        |
|  10  | Product 1 |        4        |
|  11  | Product 2 |        1        |
|  12  | Product 2 |        1        |
|  13  | Product 2 |        2        |
|  14  | Product 2 |        2        |
|  15  | Product 2 |        3        |
|  16  | Product 2 |        3        |
+------+-----------+-----------------+
```

I would like to create a query that answers me how many products were sold, by product and by month, like this:

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
|  product  |  month  |  how_many  |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| Product 1 |    1    |     1      |
| Product 1 |    2    |     2      |
| Product 1 |    3    |     2      |
| Product 1 |    4    |     5      |
| Product 1 |    5    |     0      |
| Product 1 |    6    |     0      |
| Product 1 |    7    |     0      |
| Product 1 |    8    |     0      |
| Product 1 |    9    |     0      |
| Product 1 |   10    |     0      |
| Product 1 |   11    |     0      |
| Product 1 |   12    |     0      |
| Product 2 |    1    |     2      |
| Product 2 |    2    |     2      |
| Product 2 |    3    |     2      |
| Product 2 |    4    |     0      |
| Product 2 |    5    |     0      |
| Product 2 |    6    |     0      |
| Product 2 |    7    |     0      |
| Product 2 |    8    |     0      |
| Product 2 |    9    |     0      |
| Product 2 |   10    |     0      |
| Product 2 |   11    |     0      |
| Product 2 |   12    |     0      |
+-----------+---------+------------+
```

**What I achieved by now:** if I had a similar table *without* column `product` and if I wanted to group by month, the query would be this:

```
SELECT
  a.mn, COUNT(t.sold_on_month)
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS mn UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8
   UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS a
  LEFT JOIN t
    ON t.sold_on_month = a.mn
GROUP BY a.mn;
```

So, what I really need is a query that uses the same derived table for counting months and a group by product and sold_on_month, showing `0` on `how_many` column when no products were sold on that month. Remembering I can't use CTE or temporary tables.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Tip 1.: Don't store 'Product'.  Tip 2.: Consider handling issues of data display (e.g. missing results) in application code

Comment: No need to use the sub-query. Just use SUM(how_many) and group by products and month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a distinct list of products with a query. (If you have a products table, you could reference that.)

Given only the table in the question, we could get a distinct list like this

```
  SELECT q.product
    FROM t q
   GROUP
      BY q.product
```

We can wrap that in parens as an inline view (a derived table, in the MySQL parlance) and then do a cross join to the generated list of months,

```
SELECT p.product
     , a.mn
  FROM ( -- distinct list of products 
         SELECT q.product
           FROM t q
          GROUP
             BY q.product
       ) p
 CROSS
  JOIN ( -- list of months
         SELECT 1 AS mn UNION ALL ... 
       ) a
 ORDER
    BY p.product
     , a.mn
```

And then we can add in the outer join to `t`, and do a GROUP BY and aggregate in the SELECT list ...

```
SELECT p.product
     , a.mn
  -- , IFNULL(SUM(t.qty),0)    AS tot_qty
     , COUNT(t.sold_on_month)  AS cnt_rows
  FROM ( -- distinct list of products
         SELECT q.product
           FROM t q
          GROUP
             BY q.product
       ) p
 CROSS
  JOIN ( -- list of months
         SELECT 1 AS mn UNION ALL ... 
       ) a
  LEFT
  JOIN t t
    ON t.product       = p.product
   AND t.sold_on_month = a.mn 
 GROUP
    BY p.product
     , a.mn
 ORDER
    BY p.product
     , a.mn
```

---

If you have another source for the inline view `p`, other than the table in the question (e.g. a products table with a distinct list of products), we could reference that instead.

The trick is the `CROSS JOIN` between "months" and "products".

Then an outer join to get matching rows from `t`.